# PROLOG use of arg/3 function

Tags: prolog

I have to write a **project/3** predicate in prolog that returns *true* when the third argument is a list containing the **Nth** arguments of the first list elements. If a term has less than Nth arguments, then it must be ignored.
I need to use a default predicate such as functor, arg or univ (=..).

some examples:

```
?-project([foo(bar, baz), 40 + 2, sin(x), log(16, 2)], 2, [baz, 2, 3]).
  true

?-project([3 * sin(x), 40 + 2, cos(x), 42], 2, L2).
  L2 = [sin(x), 2]
```

The code i wrote:

```
project([], _, []):- !.
project([X | Xs], N, [Z | Zs]):-arg(N, X, Z), project(Xs, N, Zs).
```

if i try, for example:

```
?- project([40 + 2, 30 - 1], 2, X).
X = [2, 1].
```

The result is good. I don't understand how to add the *"If a term has less than Nth arguments, then it must be ignored"* part in the code.

ty all

Comment: At your first test case is at least a [ bracket missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current attempt if the N is greater than the arity of the term then
`arg(N, X, Z)` will fail and as a result `project/3` will fail too:

```
?- project([foo(bar, baz), 40 + 2, sin(x), log(16, 2)], 2, L).
false.
```

So you need to handle the case where calling `arg(N, X, Z)` fails due to `N>arity of X` and just ignore term X:

```
project([], _, []):- !.
project([X | Xs], N, L):- 
                ( 
                  arg(N, X, Z) 
                     -> L =[Z|Zs], project(Xs, N, Zs)
                  ;
                  project(Xs, N, L)
                ).
```

Now if you try:

```
?- project([foo(bar, baz), 40 + 2, sin(x), log(16, 2)], 2, L).
L = [baz, 2, 2].
```

You can see it succeeds returning the right answer!!